# Is it possible to sign a transaction with Metamask that was generated elsewhere?

Tags: go, ethereum, metamask

I'm building a dApp that will generate a smart contract based on user input, and deploy that onto the Test net through Infura.

I have a React frontend which allows for the user to connect their Metamask wallet, and a Go backend that takes care of the heavy lifting of generating the .sol files and compiling the contracts.

What I would like to do is have the Backend take care of generation and deployment of the smart contract but with the account/address details of the user's Metamask.

I would prefer not having the User export their private key manually and send that to the backend.

Is it possible for a deployer account/address to be used in the backend to generate the transaction for deployment and then have it signed by the User's Metamask?